# Why can't I debug parts of code without brackets in chrome, when using react?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed that when I don't use brackets in some parts of my code (condiditional if else) I can't properly debug it in google chrome. This also happens in edge

[image: Can you check it out]

Does anybody know what is it due to?

Comment: Could be a bug in devtools, you can report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I could suppose it's something with react, when you start to learn something new a little strange usually happens :), any way it could be a problem with devtools. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you see is the source code written in JSX. Browsers can't run JSX, they can run Javascript. Your tool chain transpiles the JSX to Javascript and provides a source map that tries to allow you to put breakpoints in the original code while stopping at the execution point in the generated code. Sometimes the mapping is not exact and precise enough to allow you to pause on the exact same spot. That seems to be the case in this instance.

Comment: Definitely, I also have find more other problems, Some times the apps take a lot of time for rendering the changes while you are on dev.